# Does this sound right? - "Start by dragging into this area..."

Tags: word-order

I have this sentence, roughly in the middle of an empty screen:

"Start by dragging into this area a file or folder you would like to process."

and I'm not sure about "into this area" directly following "dragging". I would happily put the "into this area" part at the end, but a reader quickly scanning this text would not be able to make as quick a connection between "dragging" and "into this area" as when they are together, given that the part detailing what can be dragged ("a file or folder you would like to process") is rather long?

Does the original sentence sound OK to a native speaker? If not, what are your suggestions to improve it?

Comment: It's OK.  I agree with everything you've said (about it's less-than-ideal placement of "into this area" and the possible confusion produced by "start by dragging a file or folder..."), but the sentence you've written is easily readable.  An alternative might be: "Start by selecting a file or folder you would like to process and drag it into this area."

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks for your comment. While the original is understandable, I've decided to use the more traditional form, to avoid giving the reader a pause, as rpeinhardt put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It will definitely give a reader pause

It is not a typical sentence arrangement and it will read awkwardly. It will be understood, but it will definitely make the reader think about the unusual order which is a distraction that ought to be avoided.

You have correctly identified a better arrangement:

> Start by dragging a file or folder you would like to process into this area.

As *Tᴚoɯɐuo* points out, though, the sentence could be even clearer:

> Start with a file or folder you'd like to process and drag it into this area.

"Dragging a file or folder [...]" is a gerund. If you change it to a simpler verb phrase "and drag it into", the meaning of the sentence is simplified and even easier to understand.

Comment: It is quite common, though perhaps not in software how-to books, to find the prepositional phrase immediately after the verb if the direct object noun phrase is a rather lengthy one as it is in OP's example.  So I think you might say "It would give some readers pause". I don't like the alternative at all, and would rewrite *Start with a file or folder you'd like to process and drag it into this area*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That is very true. If the OP's revision is "better", your version is "best." I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: @rpeinhardt, I might add a comma before into because it's not clear whether you are dragging into the area or when you want something processed into an area. What does "into an area" modify: the dragging or the processing?

Comment: @urn I think that's unnecessary, actually, because one can "drag into" but not "process into." This prevents any confusion about what the prepositional phrase is referring to.   ---  (I realize that "process into" is a valid verb phrase if the word process is used to mean *change into*, as in "process milk into cheese," but that meaning does not make sense in the OP's context).

Comment: @rpeinhardt, it wasn't obvious to me that "process into" is not a valid scenario in the OP's posted context. For example, if his page is meant to process a file to generate a graph, "process into this area" might make perfect sense. A different structure, as in your edit, is probably cleaner anyway.

Comment: @urn But can you process (ie change) a file "into an area?" It just doesn't make sense. It's a bit moot, though. As I point out at the end of the edited answer, Tᴚoɯɐuo's suggestion is then even better than the one I first came up with because it prevents the ambiguity you see :)

Comment: @rpeinhardt The edit is interesting, but it changes the meaning of the sentence ever so slightly. I think your original suggestion would be best in this case.